# nested dictionary in Django template

Tags: django, dictionary, django-templates, nested-loops

I am using the Django template, I have met one problem with the nested dictionary.

```
{'Engineering Mathematics 1': {'Nov Dec - 2017': <FieldFile: Previous/Nov_Dec_2017.pdf>}, 
 'Engineering Physics': {'Nov Dec - 2016': <FieldFile: Previous/Nov_Dec_2016.pdf>, 
                         'Nov Dec - 2018': <FieldFile: Previous/Nov_Dec_2018.pdf>, 
                         'Nov Dec - 2019': <FieldFile: Previous/Nov_Dec_2019.pdf>, 
                         'May June - 2017': <FieldFile: Previous/May_Jun_2017.pdf>, 
                         'May June - 2018': <FieldFile: Previous/May_Jun_2018.pdf>, 
                         'May June - 2019': <FieldFile: Previous/May_Jun_2019.pdf>}}
```

I am trying to print all data in the HTML page by nested for loop. but it's not working on the HTML page. I have tried the code in Django shell and it working perfectly but when I come to HTML page it's not working.

**HTML Code**

```
{%for i, j in my_dict.items%} <----- from this line, code not working
     <h3> {{i}} </h3>
     {%for k, v in j.items%}
         {{k}} ---> {{v}}
     {%endfor%}
{%endfor%}
```

when I try the following code in HTML it prints the key_value of the main dictionary

```
{%for i in my_dict%}
     <h3> {{i}} </h3>
{%endfor%}
```

output of the above code comes
**'Engineering Mathematics 1'
'Engineering Physics'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code works fine on my django.

It print out these html.

```
Engineering Mathematics 1
Nov Dec - 2017 ---> <FieldFile: Previous/Nov_Dec_2017.pdf>
Engineering Physics
Nov Dec - 2016 ---> <FieldFile: Previous/Nov_Dec_2016.pdf> Nov Dec - 2018 ---> <FieldFile: Previous/Nov_Dec_2018.pdf> Nov Dec - 2019 ---> <FieldFile: Previous/Nov_Dec_2019.pdf> May June - 2017 ---> <FieldFile: Previous/May_Jun_2017.pdf> May June - 2018 ---> <FieldFile: Previous/May_Jun_2018.pdf> May June - 2019 ---> <FieldFile: Previous/May_Jun_2019.pdf>
```

views:

```
def index(request):

    my_dict = {
        'Engineering Mathematics 1': {'Nov Dec - 2017': '<FieldFile: Previous/Nov_Dec_2017.pdf>'}, 
        'Engineering Physics': {
            'Nov Dec - 2016': '<FieldFile: Previous/Nov_Dec_2016.pdf>', 
            'Nov Dec - 2018': '<FieldFile: Previous/Nov_Dec_2018.pdf>', 
            'Nov Dec - 2019': '<FieldFile: Previous/Nov_Dec_2019.pdf>', 
            'May June - 2017': '<FieldFile: Previous/May_Jun_2017.pdf>', 
            'May June - 2018': '<FieldFile: Previous/May_Jun_2018.pdf>', 
            'May June - 2019': '<FieldFile: Previous/May_Jun_2019.pdf>',
        }
    }
    context = {
        'my_dict': my_dict,
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

templates

```
{%for i, j in my_dict.items%}
<h3> {{i}} </h3>
{%for k, v in j.items%}
{{k}} ---> {{v}}
{%endfor%}
{%endfor%}
```

I think maybe you have some typos or some small error in views or templates?